# AuthCanceled at /oauth/complete/facebook/

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth, social-auth-app-django

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/?granted_scopes=public_profile&denied_scopes&code=AQBoM1W9l8X1lnsYCaspOQVi1nxYG1Vh3IDkdXOw1dcW5tG6dNfjzbrQ0APZlpIquhjdeMLsQ6Wd_vktM_7pCv2GI-Uqsvya7iVm7jdnX2nbaMPkF2f7JgznpVZLh5oRXQv2AvG0Syu-GZ4skYp2ZVDNvuWdfEu-OnpN_d0GsY-P07BwwsCIlIwL6CrR0GCjNK3_wSC4c8BTWXS9fPeKd7rQOZB863x9wEwVQDjCx-LgxL41_rGJlIbk01pFWPCze5GZvsFJe8xAvbzjO9E1Jrq6KGf2pddF4-78q3xLz-IG3Ary31DoSHS2POmb-KrPvMQvK96ouft-vUBUFcoEe83P&state=nTPuVRtqNf8wSmU9SiFRYozizutSAoAd

Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:[
   'admin_interface',
   'colorfield',
   'carparking.apps.CarparkingConfig',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'social_django'
]
Installed Middleware:[
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware'
]



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 248, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/facebook.py", line 97, in auth_complete
response = self.request(self.access_token_url(), params={
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 238, in request
response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

During handling of the above exception (400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: 
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=Client_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Foauth%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F&client_secret=Client_Secret&code=AQBoM1W9l8X1lnsYCaspOQVi1nxYG1Vh3IDkdXOw1dcW5tG6dNfjzbrQ0APZlpIquhjdeMLsQ6Wd_vktM_7pCv2GI-Uqsvya7iVm7jdnX2nbaMPkF2f7JgznpVZLh5oRXQv2AvG0Syu-GZ4skYp2ZVDNvuWdfEu-OnpN_d0GsY-P07BwwsCIlIwL6CrR0GCjNK3_wSC4c8BTWXS9fPeKd7rQOZB863x9wEwVQDjCx-LgxL41_rGJlIbk01pFWPCze5GZvsFJe8xAvbzjO9E1Jrq6KGf2pddF4-78q3xLz-IG3Ary31DoSHS2POmb-KrPvMQvK96ouft-vUBUFcoEe83P), another exception occurred:
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_django/views.py", line 31, in complete
return do_complete(request.backend, _do_login, user=request.user,
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/actions.py", line 45, in do_complete
user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 40, in complete
return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pratik/myproject/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 251, in wrapper
raise AuthCanceled(args[0], response=err.response)

Exception Type: AuthCanceled at /oauth/complete/facebook/
Exception Value: Authentication process canceled
```

**I think this error because of it requesting on http tell me how to redirect it to https and  SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True this is not working. and my reditect url is https://www.example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/ and also added without www https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/**

Comment: Did you build the redirect uri yourself? And did you set the correct redirect from facebook side?

Comment: added this lines in settings.pyLOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'   and this is in urls.py path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),

Comment: yes my facebook side urls is https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/ , https://www.example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/    they are in https

Comment: Try to add it as an exact value, like: `https://www.example.com/oauth/complete/facebook`

Comment: Also your client id and secret are visible in your example traceback. If that is for production you'd want to remove it

Comment: facebook cannot take http in when app is live and my app is live and this code is works perfectly on local computer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235921/discussion-between-pratik-and-bdbd).

Comment: Doesn't look like you are serving this app through https since the request url in the traceback clearly shows `http://`. Also, did you fill the client id setting in your settings.py?

Comment: hello i got the solution infact i will not call it solution but when i made some changes in urls.py and changed in redirect url of facebook then it worked
I have done these changes-
My old path in urls.py was path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')), so I changed it to path(' ', include('social_django.urls', namespace= 'social')), and my old redirect url to facebook was https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/ and i add this https://example.com/complete/facebook/ then it worked in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i got the solution infact i will not call it solution but when i made some changes in urls.py and changed in redirect url of facebook then it worked

I have done these changes-

My old path in urls.py was path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
so I changed it to path(' ', include('social_django.urls', namespace= 'social')), and my old redirect url to facebook was https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/ and i add this https://example.com/complete/facebook/ then it worked in production